# ScrollViewer on ItemsControl is always disabled

Tags: xaml, scrollbar, itemscontrol

This is my UserControl file:

```
<StackPanel>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,0,0,0">
        <Grid Width="1110">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0 0 90 0">
        <ItemsControl  MinHeight="400" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myObjectItemsTemplateSelector}" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</StackPanel>
```

Even though the ItemsControl element has a lot of items, the scrollbar is diabled. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi,is this your usercontrol inside the stackpanel ? this code is working fine in window...but if this code  in usercontrol  and usercontrol is in stackpanel is not working.

Comment: @HeenaPatil This whole code is in UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollviewer is inside of a stack panel which will size to as much room as the it's child elements need.  You can either set a max height on the scrollviewer or switch the parent container to a grid with verticalalignment of stretch which will size to as much room as available.